# Spring Boot Angular2, using mvn not loading index.html

Tags: spring, maven, angular, spring-boot, using

I have a mvn project with 2 modules, ui and server both building as jars. I am using Angular2 as the ui module and have added this dependency to the server spring boot module. Both modules build correctly but the ui is not included in the server module, when the server starts correctly it does not serve the index.html page when requested.

I have the ui Angular2 src under the standard mvn resource structure eg src/main/resources.

I have found 2 examples 1) [SpringAngular2TypeScript](http://javaee.ch/2016/02/23/spring-boot-angularjs-2-typescript-hello-world-tutorial/) which I cant get to work and 2) a gradle project.

Any suggestion would be great or a simple working example would be better.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your UI module should not be built into a JAR. It should be built into a WAR. Jars will not include any web content. Hence your index.html is not being served since it is not present in the jar in the first place.
That being said, instead on including the ui module in the server module, you can include your server module as a jar dependency in the ui module (since wars can contain jars) and deploy this WAR on your server.

Also, you shouldn't be putting all your angular code in src/main/resources. It should be put into src/main/webapp folder. See the [Standard Maven Folder Structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: Thanks. So for now it would be simpler to have one springboot module and move the angular2 code from its own module to springboot module under src/main/webapp?

Comment: Yes, you can do this as well. You will end up generating just one artifact, that is the WAR(this would have your spring boot  code in src/main/java and the angular code in src/main/webapp). Check this [link](https://github.com/KartikShankarappa/RRS-Spring-and-Hibernate-/tree/master/RestaurantReservationSystem/RRSRestApp) for a sample application. Instead, if you still want to generate 2 artifacts, then like I have mentioned already in my answer before,you should include the server module(jar) as a dependency into the angular ui module (war) and deploy the war to the server.